# Why this regex doesn't exclude this word?

Tags: php, regex

I have this code :

```
$str=preg_replace(
    '#\b[^"](Hello User)#',         
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
    $str);
return nl2br($str);
```

So, I'd like to replace every occurences of `Hello User` that doesnt start with `"`.

For example with string :

```
Hello User\n
"Hello User\n
Hello User\n
"Hello User"\n
```

I'll aspect this result :

```
<a href="Hello User">Hello User</a><br />
"Hello User<br />
<a href="Hello User">Hello User</a><br />
"Hello User"<br />
```

But in fact the output is the opposite :

```
Hello User<br />
"<a href="Hello User">Hello User</a><br />
Hello User<br />
"<a href="Hello User">Hello User</a>"<br />
```

Why? And how can I fix this trouble?

**EDIT**

You can see an example here http://codepad.org/2Q466lx2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `[^"]` expects to match a character (anything but a `"`). Since your first `Hello User` is at the start of the string, it fails.

Use a negative lookbehind assertion instead:

```
$str=preg_replace(
    '#(?<!")(Hello User)#',           
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
    $str);
```

This matches `Hello User` only if it is not preceded by a `"`.

Comment: Uhm no! Using this all Hello User are replaced :O

Comment: Really? No it doesnt works (or maybe you misunderstand my question :)). Just check it out this one http://codepad.org/2Q466lx2 : the last `"Hello User` (which is preceded by `"`) is matched :O

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker : can you help me please? :)

Comment: Well, in your code you call `htmlentities` which (as you can see from your output) converts `"` into `&quot;`. You then pass that string to your function `example`. So in that case `#(?<!&quot;)(Hello User)#` should work.

Comment: Oh right! So [^"] will work for my project, because it should replace only link that are not matched with a previously bbcode. Perfect, nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

Function htmlentities() convert `"` to `&quot;` try:

```
#(?<!&quot;)(Hello User)#
```